# write a simple shell program to show a loader in TUI

Tags: shell

I am thinking of writing a simple shell program that will show an output in the console about the percentage work completed.
something like thiss:-

```
2%==>
```

which will increase the arrow with respect to the work done.
I donot want to print the loader every time in a new line.
what should be my approach?'
***I often see this thing is used in wget and similar commands** 

TIA

Comment: Search for and read about *carriage return*.

Comment: Do you want a prebuilt component that can be used for the job? If so, I'd suggest http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml

Comment: no, I dont want any pre-built components, this is just a fun exercise that i want to do from scratch @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the line the cursor is on, send a CR ("carriage return", `\r`) to send ("return") the cursor to the beginning of the existing line, from which you can print new contents. Contrast this to the newline (`\n`), which moves the cursor to a new line.

To see this in action, try running the following:

```
printf '%s\r' "Existing contents being written here"
sleep 1
printf '%s\r' "New contents being written here     "
sleep 1
printf '%s\n' "Writing final contents and moving to a new line"
printf '%s\n' "This is written to a second line."
```

Note how the second line has some extra whitespace on the end; this padding is there to make sure that the end of the original line's contents are overwritten.

---

That said, if you just want a status bar already built for you, there are numerous solutions for that already:

- [pv (Pipe Viewer)](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) will do all the math for you, including with large streams, binary streams, etc.
- The dialog program contains a "gauge" widget, with similar functionality. [See this example of its usage on Unix StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44860/making-a-progressbar-with-dialog-from-rsync-output).

Comment: exactly the thing that is was looking for, is the %s doing the carriage return?
thanks a lot

Comment: No, it's the `\r`; the `%s` is the placeholder that specifies where your text (given in the next argument) will go.

Comment: ...so, `printf 'foo\r'` will print `foo`, then send the cursor back to the beginning of the same line, ready to have something else written over it. The purpose of the `%s` placeholder and then your string in a separate argument is so you don't need to make sure your string doesn't contain other contents special to printf. (If you want backslash-escapes processed but nothing else, consider `%b` instead).